# Microcontroller clock speed vs internal oscillator

Tags: oscillator, clock

I'm having a little trouble understanding the difference between an internal oscillator and clock speed of microcontrollers. I was under the impression the the internal oscillator oscillates at a certain frequency which IS the clock speed but I get the feeling that I'm wrong. I've seen the PIC16F690 datasheet that says that the oscillator can run up to 8MHz but the clock speed is 20MHz. Or is that 20MHz a maximum if an external clock is used?

Comment: That question has "ARM" in the title, but actually has nothing to do with the core being an ARM.

Comment: A general answer could be anything. Some CPUs take an internal or external clock and multiply it to a much faster internal clock (laptops running at 2.x GHz may have a 50-100MHz clock, and reprogram the multiplier for different performance and heat levels. PICs generally don't! Set the osc to 8 MHz and that's what you'll get. Turn it off and feed external 20MHz and it'll run at 20 MHz. A fine reading of teh datasheet should have all the gory details.

Comment: Does this help?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_multiplier

Answer (score 0):

The midrange series PIC chips generally run at a clock frequency of the external crystal divided by 4. There are 4 t-states in each cycle, full details can be found in the reference manuals. Each instruction takes one or two cycles.

So an external crystal of 20MHz will result in a 5MHz (200ns) cycle.

The internal RC oscillator can run at up to 8MHz (no pins used, no external parts but very poor accuracy compared to a crystal or even a resonator). At 8MHz you will have a 2MHz clock rate at the CPU.

---

These 8-bit midrange PIC chips are extremely simple. Modern 32-bit MCUs often have PLLs and fractional PLLs as well as dividers that can generate a huge range of frequencies from one crystal or external (or internal) source. This becomes more and more necessary as you need things like Ethernet, I2S and so on that each demand different frequencies at tight tolerances.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the microcontrollers support external clock oscillator, but also have a built-in one. You can set the fuses to decide which one to use (through software, before writing your code).

Things to know: 20MHz sounds like maximum external xtal frequency. Internal is 8MHz (of course, it's individual for every MCU, but these are pretty common values for many different simple MCUs). So you can actually use internal oscillator without any external (which frees up 2 pins as a bonus). Cons: internal oscillator is usually less accurate. Everything should still work fine tho. See datasheet of your MCU for more detail.

Another important point is a Prescaler. Also set in fuses. Before your clock signal (either external OR internal) is actually fed into the CPU core, the prescaler can divide it. For example by a factor of 4. or 2. Or 1 (no division). So 20MHz external clock with prescaler set to 2 will mean your MCU will run at 10MHz. If you are not crunching numbers or sending data at high (relatively to clock) speed, you can run at lower clock and consume less power even with the higher frequency xtal. ADD: prescaler can be applied to the internal clock as well.

Point number next: MCU voltage has to be matched with the core frequency. If you want to run at maximum or close to maximum clock, you will likely have to use maximum voltage. All of that data is in datasheet. AVR MCUs (like Arduino's atmega328p) care about clock AFTER prescaler. So atmega328p @ 16MHz XTAL @ Prescaler=1 will run at 16MHz and require 5V, it will not run at 3.3V. But atmega328p @ 16MHz XTAL @ Prescaler=4 will run at 4MHz and can happily work at 3.3V (and at 5V of course as well - higher works, lower doesn't). Prescaler is often not mentioned in discussions as it's usually effective clock frequency after prescaler everyone talks about by default, since it's prescaled clock that everything depends on, not the original xtal frequency. So when someone says "I have MCU at 8MHz", it already means "core clock after prescaler is 8MHz".

Things may (or may not) be slightly different for the other MCU manufacturers, that's what the datasheet is for :)

Answer (score 0):

The 20MHz maximum frequency only applies when you apply +Vdd above 4.5V. At lower Vdd voltages, you must use a slower clock frequency:

[image: Vdd versus clock frequency]

To run at 20MHz, you have three options:

- An external 20MHz oscillator with logic-level output applied to pin OSC1
- An external 20MHz crystal applied between pins OSC1, OSC2, plus 2 capacitors to Vss.
- An external 20MHz ceramic resonator applied between pins OSC1, OSC2, plus 2 capacitors.

With a 20MHz clock, the *fastest* instructions require 200ns. GOTO, CALL, RETURN instructions require 400ns.
You can also run at slower frequencies, using an internal (not-so-accurate-frequency) clock. This clock tops out at 8 MHz., and yields fastest instruction rate of 500 ns. 
Clock selection is done with "fuses" (Microchip calls this "configuration word") and this is done when the chip is programmed. An internal register can also be written by your user program to change frequencies of the internal clock. Do read the data sheet - it is only 256 pages.